# Add custom attributes with product quotation and save in product orders

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, custom-attributes, sales-order-item

Add custom attributes (i.e hire start date & hire end date in below picture) with product quotation and save in product orders items details.

[image: Front End layout for newly added custom attributes]

I want these attributes should be visible on checkout page. And must be submitted with orders/quotations for each product in cart.

Then these attributes values must be visible in order items for admin in order details.

[image: Order Custom attribute in admin]

Any reference link or hello world example will be appreciated...

Comment: This link is what I was looking for.

http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/magento-add-comment-box-to-each-product-in-cart/

Still need to test how I can apply it in magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

This exact feature is available in following plugin.

https://marketplace.magento.com/amanweb-cartcomment.html

This is providing one custom comment field for each product.
We can scale & get two custom fields and save with quotations.